# Ignore SafeArea inside NavigationView

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationview

I am creating simple app with swiftui. In my app, I have 2 screens "ContentView" and "Home".

In my Content View,

```
struct ContentView : View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                
                //Some views
                  NavigationLink(isActive: self.$routeHome, destination: {Home},label: {
                Text("Home")})

                .navigationBarTitle("title")
            }
.navigationBarTitle("Page1")
        }
    }
}
```

and In Home,

```
struct Home : View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
        Color.red.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
       ScrollView{
           //some views
                 }
             }.navigationBarTitle("Home")
        }
   }
```

the `Red` color takes entire screen at first. but when I scroll, the `NavigationView`  area is not in red color anymore. In my actual code, I want to show red color for all spaces when I click on button inside scrollview. Please help me to accomplish this in SwiftUI.

Answer (score 1):

NavigationBar is colored by top child scrollView's offset.
If you want to always hide navigationBar background, you can use `toolbarBackground()` like following code.

```
struct Home : View {
    var body: some View {
        ...
        .navigationBarTitle("Home")
        .toolbarBackground(.hidden, for: .navigationBar) // Added
    }
}
```

P.S. I tried this codes with iPhone simulator 16.2

Comment: Sorry. `toolbarBackground(.hidden, for: .navigationBar)` not being resolved.

Comment: Did you try with posted code? I tried with it. The toolbarBackground should put on top child view.
If you tried with different view hierarchy, it may not be able to resolve.

Comment: I copied your code and paste it. I got `Value of type 'some View' has no member 'toolbarBackground'` Error.

Comment: The `toolbarBackground` introduced iOS 16.0. Do you use iOS lower than 16?

Comment: I am targeting to iOS 15. Is there alternative to `toolbarBackground`?

Comment: You can use `UIAppearance` instead of `toolbarBackground` but I'm not recommend it.

Comment: Thank you. So I have to upgrade my project to iOS 16.

Answer (score -1):

To ignore the safe area inside a NavigationView in SwiftUI, you can use the `edgesIgnoringSafeArea(_:)` modifier and pass it the .top and/or .bottom edges, like this:

```
NavigationView {
    VStack {
        // your content here
    }
    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)
    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.bottom)
}
```

This will allow the content of the `VStack` to extend under the top and bottom safe areas of the `NavigationView`. Note that this may cause the content to overlap with the system status bar and the navigation bar, so you may need to adjust the layout or add additional padding or spacing as needed.

Alternatively, you can use the `.navigationBarHidden(true)` modifier to hide the navigation bar entirely and allow the content to extend to the edges of the screen.

```
NavigationView {
    VStack {
        // your content here
    }
    .navigationBarHidden(true)
}
```